# MongoDB centos7 unable to run with a non standard port as a service

Tags: mongodb, runtime-error, centos7

I installed mongodb on a fresh centos 7
I run `sudo service mongod` start without any problem
When I change the port in `/etc/mongod.conf` and I restart the mongod service I get the following error

From `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

> 2014-11-11T07:38:29.495+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=12401 port=27022 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=awscm001
>   2014-11-11T07:38:29.495+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.5
>   2014-11-11T07:38:29.495+0000 [initandlisten] git version: e99d4fcb4279c0279796f237aa92fe3b64560bf6
>   2014-11-11T07:38:29.495+0000 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build8.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
>   2014-11-11T07:38:29.495+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
>   2014-11-11T07:38:29.495+0000 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { port: 27021 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
>   2014-11-11T07:38:29.497+0000 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongo/journal
>   2014-11-11T07:38:29.497+0000 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
>   2014-11-11T07:38:29.679+0000 [initandlisten] **ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:13 Permission denied for socket: 0.0.0.0:27022**
>   2014-11-11T07:38:29.680+0000 [initandlisten] now exiting
>   2014-11-11T07:38:29.680+0000 [initandlisten] dbexit:
>   2014-11-11T07:38:29.680+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
>   2014-11-11T07:38:29.680+0000 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...

I am able though to run with a different port with the following command

```
sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

When I run as a service user mongod runs mongodb
When I run from command line root runs mongodb

How can run the mongodb service with a different port?
By the way I succeeded on centos 6.5
Thanks

Comment: Check if this port is in use by some other application using netstat command.

Comment: I did netstat | grep 27022, nothing returned

Comment: Try with some other port??

Comment: I tried already, it does not work, there is nothing special about 27022, but it seems that there is something special about 27017

Comment: Looks like mongod has not stopped properly. You can try 'sudo mongod stop' or 'pkill mongod' and then relogin and verify.

Comment: doing sudo service mongod stop works, I noticed though that /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock was not removed, I deleted it, changed the port value in the mongo.conf file did a sudo service mongod start and I still get the same error

Comment: Could you show the content of your config file? It seems you're setting the port 27021

Comment: The problem is fixed. I found the solution a few month ago while browsing the internet. The solution to the problem was solved by chcon -Rv system_u:object_r:mongod_var_lib_t:s0 /data/dbw . I changed the port and the default location of the database.
When changing the default location of the database you need to update selinux.

Answer (score 0):

for those people having problem like me.. my fix is allow mongodb custom port on semanage

```
semanage port --list | grep mongo
mongod_port_t                  tcp      27017-27019, 28017-28019
```

as you can see, only 27017-27019, 28017-28019 is allowed.
in order to add a custom port for mongodb

```
semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 21010
```

you now have added the custom port

```
 semanage port --list | grep mongo

 mongod_port_t                  tcp      21010, 27017-27019, 28017-28019
```

**make sure to restart mongodb**